# Chrome doesn’t handle custom protocols correctly

Tags: google-chrome, network-protocols, address-bar

For example, if I enter `steam://connect/127.0.0.1` in the Omnibox, it will search for the URL instead of launching the program that handles that protocol.

How can Chrome be configured to treat custom protocols correctly?

Comment: Did you ever get the dialog box asking you for permission to launch an external program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be adjusted in Chrome's `Local State` file.

The exact location depends on your OS. For example:

- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State` on Windows 7.
- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local State` on Mac OS X 10.8.
- `~/.config/google-chrome/Local State` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Steps:

1. Close Google Chrome.
2. Open the `Local State` file and search for `excluded_schemes` in `protocol_handler`.
3. Add the line

   ```
   "steam": false,
   ```

   to `excluded_schemes`.
4. Restart Google Chrome.

Comment: Hmm, that’s strange. `ed2k://` and `magnet:` work fine without having to manually change anything. What’s special/wrong with `steam://`? Maybe the program didn’t register the protocol correctly? I assume that Steam has an *associate* function…

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose Google has those predefined. There's no entry for any of the common protocols: `http`, `ftp`, etc. I just know I had to add it for Skype.

Comment: Nope. I just checked and Chrome does not include any protocols by default (create a new profile and then check the `Local State` file; it will not even have a `protocol_handler` section). Further, setting it to `true` does not make it search, it makes it do nothing whatsoever, so that can’t be the problem.

Comment: By *by default*, I meant that Chrome recognized the protocol natively, so there's no need to create a `Local State` entry. But that's just a guess. I don't know if the `"steam": false,` entry is the *proper* way to achieve this, but it definitely worked for `skype://` .

Comment: Do you mean that it was set to `true` for Skype?

Comment: No, it was just missing. But whether it's missing or set to `true`, Skype links aren't recognized. That might be a bug, as far as the `true` entry is concerned.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for every protocol rather than adding them one by one manually?

Comment: @MMavipc: Not that I know of. This would also have the unpleasant side effect of `typo://url` silently failing.

Comment: Where's this file under Linux?

Comment: @Behrang: As stated in my answer, the file's full path is `~/.config/google-chrome/Local State` on Ubuntu 12.04. I wouldn't know about other distributions.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. We had to modify this to get the Atlassian SourceTree handler to work. Thanks!

Comment: Right now on Windows 10 this setting is located in the file: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

Answer (score 1):

As a reference it looks like Custom URIs not being followed in the Omnibox or when passed as a command line parameter is [known issue 560809 in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=560809).

As of writing the issue does not describe any workarounds :/

Comment: Looks like this issue was fixed April 10 2018. Version 66.0.3359.170 works. Woo!